# Android Signed EditText

Tags: android

I need use numberSigned EditText.

EditText works but i have a problem with entering numbers with a minus.

Take a number in this way:

```
charsEntered = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
```

Numbers without minus works ok but when i need enter for example -3 it don't works.

Comment: does it gives only 3 for -3??

Comment: What I mean is that it draws such as math and I have: 2 - 3, the result is -1 -1 as I type it does not work. If the task jst 2 +2 = 4, and type 4 is working

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by "it doesn't work". You cannot type -1-1 in a numberSigned EditText. There can be only 1 minus, and it must be the first char

Comment: Badly written. In TextView I display a "mission" for example, 1-2. The user enters the EditText result -1. And it does not work. If the task is 1 +1 and you give a score of 2 things work. Do not operate with a response.

Answer (score 1):

Use in your `XML layout` the following :

```
<EditText
    ....
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following to get **signed number**

```
String tmpstr = et.getText().toString();

charsEntered = Integer.parseInt(tmpstr);

if(tmpstr.charAt(0).equals("-")) {
    charsEntered *= (-1) ;
}
```

Comment: But you have to take two edit-textes for taking two different numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is not the best solution for me

Comment: I just suggested you the way which I knew.